# Multiple Images for categories in magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, image-upload, category-attribute

I need to upload multiple images for categories like in products in Magento 2. How can I do this?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: No, this requirement was later dropped by client, so we didn't worked on it.